# Permission denied to enable service [cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcp

As account owner, I run the command:

```
gcloud services enable cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com --project xxxx
```

and get the error message:

> **ERROR:** (gcloud.services.enable) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
> to enable service [cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com]

Notice: I'm "Google Cloud AI Trusted Tester program user", trying to enable the Duet AI API to a project

Comment: Search your emails for "Google Cloud Trusted Testers Program". You should have received a notification that the API/service was enabled for you. The email also has a link to a form if you have problems. If you do not have that email, send an email to one of the PMs on the "Trusted Tester" emails.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact the Support team to help you grant the permission needed to enable the service [[cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com](http://cloudaicompanion.googleapis.com)]. It seems that they need to reach out to the Product team to grant the permissions needed

Comment: It seems that my Cloud Trusted Testers Program wasn't active yet..